# Is Worklight App Center able to distribute app to Windows 8 Tablet

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I wonder how I can distribute an app via Worklight App Center to a Winodws 8 tablet, with latest Worklight 6.2. If it's supported, can you point where I can find the instructions?

I'm able to generate the appx file via MS Visual Studio 2013 Professional. But when I tried to upload it to the App Center, it's saying 'Wrong file extension' and doesn't allow me to move to next step. My Worklight App Center version is [Version: 01-20141015-1508].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Application Center supports: Android, BlackBerry 6/7, iOS and Windows Phone 8.
Windows 8 is not supported.

From: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/c_concept_of_the_application_cen.html

> The Application Center manages mobile applications; it supports any
>   kind of Android, iOS, Windows Phone 8, or BlackBerry OS 6 or OS 7
>   application, including applications that are built on top of the
>   Worklight® platform.

The last line means any Worklight-based apps, for the mentioned operating systems.